# Compute the mean of each element, the previous and the next in a row vector, for all elements starting from the second one - vectorized implementation

Tags: octave

I'd like to compute the mean of each element, the previous and the next in a row vector, for all elements starting from the second one, and I'd like to do it with a vectorized implementation.

Suppose I have this row vector:

```matlab
a = [4, 7, 1, 3, 2];
```

what I want to obtain is:

```matlab
b = [4, 3.66, 2, 1.66];
```

which is, in turn, the mean of the subsequent triplets:
[4 7 1], [7 1 3], [1 3 2], [3 2 0] (the zero is conventional).
By the way, approximation to two figures is irrelevant here, it's just for the sake of the example.

I have come up with this code:

```matlab
a = [4 7 1 3 2];

function shifted = generateShiftedValues(rowVec)
    shifted = rowVec;
    for i=2:3
        shifted(i, :) = [rowVec(1, i:end), zeros(1, i-1)];
    endfor
endfunction

b = mean(generateShiftedValues(a)(:, 1:end-1), 1)
```

but what *I'd like to have is a fully vectorized implementation*.

Is that possible? Any ideas?
Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Convolution is the key to success.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67650)

I would go for this:

```matlab
a = [4 7 1 3 2]

n = 3;

b = conv(a, ones(n, 1)) / n;
b = b(3:end-1)


a =
   4   7   1   3   2

b =
   4.00000   3.66667   2.00000   1.66667
```

One could easily build a generalized solution for any number of elements to be averaged and arbitrary "starting point". If you need such, maybe provide a general description in your question. If that "special case" is sufficient, that's all.

Hope that helps!

Comment: yep, it was very helpful, thanks! I will provide a more generalized description to my problem as you suggested, as soon as possible